# How to change button background color on click and make it stick in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, background

I have a test inside my app, so when you click on the button it changes color to green if it is correct. The background color change is done and working fine, but I would like to make the button green after the click even if users do not press it anymore. Is it possible to make background color change and keep it like that?

Here is my current code:

```
                        Consumer<LevelState>(
                    builder: (context, levelState, child) =>
                    FilledButton(
                    onPressed: ()  {
                        if (_buttonpressed = true)
                        // if (score != null )
                        {
                  
                          levelState.setProgress((10).round());
                          levelState.evaluate();
                            {
                              if (score != null)
                                {
                                  // GoRouter.of(context).go('/play/won',extra: {'score': score});
                                }
                            }
                         }
                        else if (score == null)
                        {
                         GoRouter.of(context).go('/');
                        }
                    },
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                    fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(320, 40)),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return Color(0xFF55A318);
                    return  Color(0XFFE4DBC8);
                  }, 
                ),
              ),
                      
                      child: Text('NOT TO REPOST', style: 
                          TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF000000), 
                          fontSize: 14,
                          letterSpacing: 5,
                          fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
              ),
              
              ),
```

Comment: It's possible by managing a state and using conditional to determine the button's color, but the behavior fits better with an [InputChip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputChip-class.html) or [ActionChip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ActionChip-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please review the code below, which I hope will be helpful to you.

Define a boolean variable to track whether the button has been pressed

```
bool _buttonPressed = false;
```

Inside your Widget tree, where you have your Consumer widget wrapping `FilledButton`:

```
onPressed: _buttonPressed ? null : () {
  setState(() {
    // Update the button state to indicate it has been pressed
    _buttonPressed = true;

    // Your logic when the button is pressed goes here
    levelState.setProgress((10).round());
    levelState.evaluate();

    if (score != null) {
      // GoRouter.of(context).go('/play/won', extra: {'score': score});
    }
  });
},
style: ButtonStyle(
  fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(320, 40)),
  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      // Change the color based on the button state
      if (_buttonPressed) {
        return Color(0xFF55A318); // Green color
      } else {
        return Color(0XFFE4DBC8); // Default color
      }
    },
  ),
),
```